# mysql select for update read committed deadlock

Tags: mysql, deadlock, read-committed

mysql version:5.7.23-log

isolation level:read committed

mysql data

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for app_record_lock_test
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `app_record_lock_test`;
CREATE TABLE `app_record_lock_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cluster` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `namespace` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `service` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pod` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cluster_hash` (`cluster`,`hash`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=120236025 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of app_record_lock_test
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `app_record_lock_test` VALUES ('120236012', '1', 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-18 14:14:59', '2022-02-09 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO `app_record_lock_test` VALUES ('120236013', '2', 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-18 14:14:59', '2022-02-09 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO `app_record_lock_test` VALUES ('120236014', '3', 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-18 14:14:59', '2022-02-09 10:00:00');
```

session 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT HASH 
FROM
  app_record_lock_test 
WHERE
  cluster = 'cluster'  FOR UPDATE;

INSERT INTO app_record_lock_test ( HASH, cluster, namespace, service, pod, updated_at )
VALUES
  ( 1, 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-09 10:00:00' ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = '2022-02-09 11:00:01';

COMMIT;
```

session 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT HASH 
FROM
  app_record_lock_test 
WHERE
  cluster = 'cluster' FOR UPDATE;

INSERT INTO app_record_lock_test ( HASH, cluster, namespace, service, pod, updated_at )
VALUES
  ( 1, 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-09 10:00:00' ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = '2022-02-09 11:00:01';

COMMIT;
```

Steps to reproduce

1、session 1 first execute select for update

2、session 2 execute select for update

3、session 1 executes insert，This is session 2 and an error will be reported

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

why is this?

show engine innodb status,before insert:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-02-21 16:13:48 0x7f2026049700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 421085334, ACTIVE 8 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 41539545, OS thread handle 139773723899648, query id 20729357470 10.190.176.247 console Sending data
/* ApplicationName=DBeaver 21.3.5 - SQLEditor <Script-8.sql> */ SELECT HASH 
FROM
  app_record_lock_test 
WHERE
  cluster = 'cluster' FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 12005 page no 4 n bits 72 index cluster_hash of table `console`.`app_record_lock_test` trx id 421085334 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ec; asc  *  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 421085333, ACTIVE 13 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 41539561, OS thread handle 139776053516032, query id 20729357538 10.190.176.247 console update
/* ApplicationName=DBeaver 21.3.5 - SQLEditor <Script-5.sql> */ INSERT INTO app_record_lock_test ( HASH, cluster, namespace, service, pod, updated_at )
VALUES
  ( 1, 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-09 10:00:00' ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = '2022-02-09 11:00:01'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 12005 page no 4 n bits 72 index cluster_hash of table `console`.`app_record_lock_test` trx id 421085333 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ec; asc  *  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 12005 page no 4 n bits 72 index cluster_hash of table `console`.`app_record_lock_test` trx id 421085333 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ec; asc  *  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

after insert:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-02-22 09:26:16 0x7f216925a700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 421416755, ACTIVE 22 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 41565582, OS thread handle 139778307692288, query id 20731658463 10.190.176.247 console Sending data
/* ApplicationName=DBeaver 21.3.5 - SQLEditor <Script-8.sql> */ SELECT HASH 
FROM
  app_record_lock_test 
WHERE
  cluster = 'cluster' FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 12005 page no 4 n bits 72 index cluster_hash of table `console`.`app_record_lock_test` trx id 421416755 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ec; asc  *  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 421416754, ACTIVE 26 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 41565555, OS thread handle 139781474723584, query id 20731658615 10.190.176.247 console update
/* ApplicationName=DBeaver 21.3.5 - SQLEditor <Script-5.sql> */ INSERT INTO app_record_lock_test ( HASH, cluster, namespace, service, pod, updated_at )
VALUES
  ( 1, 'cluster', 'namespace', 'service', 'pod', '2022-02-09 10:00:00' ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = '2022-02-09 11:00:01'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 12005 page no 4 n bits 72 index cluster_hash of table `console`.`app_record_lock_test` trx id 421416754 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ec; asc  *  ;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000002; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ed; asc  *  ;;

Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000003; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ee; asc  *  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 12005 page no 4 n bits 72 index cluster_hash of table `console`.`app_record_lock_test` trx id 421416754 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 636c7573746572; asc cluster;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 2: len 4; hex 872aa7ec; asc  *  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: Check out what innodb status monitor says about the deadlock - it will tell you exactly what locks are causing the deadlock.

Comment: I tried show engine innodb status, the specific information has been added, but I can't see which part of the problem is.

Comment: Remove the self-incrementing primary key in the table, the problem will be solved